# Probability of picking at least 3 green balls and atmost 1 red and 1 orange ball from 4 different balls in 6 tries

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

Few days ago I [asked almost same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3884508/probability-of-picking-at-least-3-green-balls-and-atmost-1-red-ball-from-4) about 3 or more and atmost 1 red balls and thanks to very helpful answers I can calculate any kind of combinations using only two different items(balls).

Now I am facing problem with generalizing this approach. E.I. how this formula $$p=\sum_{j=3}^6 P(\text{green$=j$ and red$=0$})+\sum_{j=3}^5 P(\text{green$=j$ and red$=1$}).$$

transform for the case where ${green}\ge3, \text{red}\le1,\text{orange}\le1$ is required.

Calculating "static" values (E.I ${green}=2, red=1, orange=1$) is breeze with multinomial distribution but these cumulative values really trips me off

Comment: Do the same, count the cases of $ 3/4/5G, 1R, 0O$, $3/4G, 1R, 1O$, etc.

Comment: It's gonna get out of hand really fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the key to this problem is to forgo elegance and count, focusing directly on the # of green balls selected.

> Probability of picking at least 3 green balls and at most 1 red and 1 orange ball from 4 different balls in 6 tries

My answer will be

$$ \frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

Clearly,

$$D = 4^6.$$

I will compute various numerators $N_1, N_2, N_3, N_4$. Then

$$N = N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + N_4.$$

Assume that the colors are represented by G,R,O, and B (for black). 
On each line below, the number of ways that a distribution can occur will be counted.

$\underline{\text{3 Greens} : N_1}$

GGGBBB : $~ \binom{6}{3}.$ 
GGGBBR : $~ \binom{6}{3} \times 3.$ 
GGGBBO : $~ \binom{6}{3} \times 3.$ 
GGGBRO : $~ \binom{6}{3} \times 3!.$ 
$$N_1 = \binom{6}{3} \times 13.$$

$\underline{\text{4 Greens} : N_2}$

GGGGBB : $~ \binom{6}{4}.$ 
GGGGBR : $~ \binom{6}{4} \times 2.$ 
GGGGBO : $~ \binom{6}{4} \times 2.$ 
GGGGRO : $~ \binom{6}{4} \times 2.$ 
$$N_2 = \binom{6}{4} \times 7.$$

$\underline{\text{5 Greens} : N_3}$

GGGGGB : $~ \binom{6}{5}.$ 
GGGGGR : $~ \binom{6}{5}.$ 
GGGGGO : $~ \binom{6}{5}.$ 
$$N_3 = \binom{6}{5} \times 3.$$

$\underline{\text{6 Greens} : N_4}$

GGGGGG : $~ \binom{6}{6}.$ 
$$N_4 = \binom{6}{6} \times 1.$$

final answer:

$$\frac{
\left[\binom{6}{3} \times 13\right] ~+~
\left[\binom{6}{4} \times 7\right] ~+~
\left[\binom{6}{5} \times 3\right] ~+~
\left[\binom{6}{6} \times 1\right]
}
{4^6}.
$$